# How to enable printer discovery using DNS-SD?

Tags: linux, centos, printer, cups, mdns

On Centos 8, I run `lpinfo --include-schemes dnssd -v` to discover printers, as suggested by [CUPS documentation](https://www.cups.org/doc/network.html). Suspiciously, the command returns immediately without discovering anything.

tcpdump finds that no traffic with port 5353 is generated. Other servers running Debian Buster or Ubuntu do generate such traffic when discovering printers.

I try a nonsensical scheme `lpinfo --include-schemes blabla -v` with the same result, i.e. no error message. Which makes me wonder if the CUPS installation on that Centos server understands *dnssd*.

I found that Avahi was not installed. Not sure if it's required, but it is now installed, and the avahi-daemon is running, but the behavior is the same.

**Do I have to enable, configure, install anything on Centos to make printer discovery work?**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you didn't configure local hostname resolution for avahi. That is necessary for cups to use printers via dnssd. To be honest, it should not be necessary for discovering those printers, only for printing on them, but I would still check it.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Avahi

> Avahi provides local hostname resolution using a "hostname.local" naming scheme. To enable it, install the nss-mdns package and start/enable avahi-daemon.service.
>
> Then, edit the file /etc/nsswitch.conf and change the hosts line to include mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] before resolve and dns:
>
> *hosts: mymachines mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname dns*